# Android L Preview Material styled Tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

In the new [Design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) (scroll down to the bottom) you can see how tabs should look in the new Material design. `TabHost` however still looks very Holo to me, with no bottom line animation and no ripples effect. Is it something we have to implement ourselves?

Comment: The design guidelines don't match up perfectly with the implementations in L-preview yet. You will not need to implement these manually.

Comment: That's nice to hear. If you post it as an answer, I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The design guidelines don't match up perfectly with the implementations in L-preview yet. You will not need to implement these manually.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs) there is a custom Library that uses v7 Toolbar like TabWidget with the new Material Design animations, but it is in fully development.